# Persisted item in one context but Core Data can't find item in another context?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, core-data

In my app, I have the following method to check for the next item to display,

```
- (void)displayIfPossible:(NSNumber *)orderId {
    NSParameterAssert(orderId);
    NSLog(@"displayIfPossible orderId:%@", [orderId stringValue]);

    ItemStore *itemStore = [ItemStore sharedInstance];
    Item *currentItem = [itemStore getItemByOrderId:orderId];

    if (!currentItem) {
        NSLog(@"Fetching next(): currentItem doens't exist");
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            [itemStore fetchItemsForFeed:^{
                // TODO FIXME figure out why there's infinite recursion here
                // TEMP FIX: run app once, fetch, stop run again.
                [self displayIfPossible:orderId];
            } withFailureBlock:^{
                [self updateStatus:@"Failed to fetch new items"];
            }];
        });
        return;
    }

    self.item = currentItem;
}
```

If currentItem doesn't exist, fetchItems will query the server and persist into the Core Data. When fetchItems has finished, it will execute its callback which would be displayIfPossible again.

This is fetchItems

```
- (void)fetchItems:(void (^)(void))callback
  withFailureBlock:(void (^)(void))failureBlock
       withRequestPath:(NSString *)path
            withStatus:(NSNumber *)status {
    APIClient *client = [APIClient sharedManager];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:path parameters:nil];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = \
    [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

        // Create a new managed object context and set its persistent store coordinator
        // Note that this **must** be done here because this context belongs to another thread
        AppDelegate *theDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [localContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[theDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator]];

        for (id itemJson in JSON) {
            Item *item = [[ItemStore sharedInstance] getItemByCid:NULL_TO_NIL([itemJson valueForKey:@"id"])];
            if (item == nil) {
                Item *newItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item" \
                                                              inManagedObjectContext:localContext];
                newItem.cid = NULL_TO_NIL([itemJson valueForKey:@"id"]);
                newItem.title = NULL_TO_NIL([itemJson valueForKey:@"title"]);
                newItem.url = NULL_TO_NIL([itemJson valueForKey:@"url"]);
                newItem.image_url = NULL_TO_NIL([itemJson valueForKey:@"image_url"]);
                newItem.order_id = @([[self largestOrderId] intValue] + 1);
                newItem.status = status;

                NSError *error;
                if (![localContext save:&error]) {
                    NSLog(@"Error saving: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"fetchItems persisting item cid:%@ order_id:%@", newItem.cid, newItem.order_id);
                }
            }
        }

        if (callback != nil) {
            callback();
        }
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request , NSURLResponse *response , NSError *error , id JSON) {
        if (failureBlock) {
            failureBlock();
        }
        NSLog(@"[ItemStore fetchItems] failed. error:%@ response:%@ JSON:%@",
              [error localizedDescription], response, JSON);
    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

So I am currently seeing an infinite recursion here:

```
2013-02-18 12:10:07.013 Giordano.iPhone[5946:c07] Unknown class Lik in Interface Builder file.
2013-02-18 12:10:07.040 Giordano.iPhone[5946:c07] displayIfPossible orderId:0
2013-02-18 12:10:07.041 Giordano.iPhone[5946:c07] Fetching next(): currentItem doens't exist
2013-02-18 12:10:07.483 Giordano.iPhone[5946:c07] displayIfPossible orderId:0
2013-02-18 12:10:07.484 Giordano.iPhone[5946:c07] Fetching next(): currentItem doens't exist
2013-02-18 12:10:07.885 Giordano.iPhone[5946:c07] displayIfPossible orderId:0
2013-02-18 12:10:07.886 Giordano.iPhone[5946:c07] Fetching next(): currentItem doens't exist
2013-02-18 12:10:08.325 Giordano.iPhone[5946:c07] displayIfPossible orderId:0
2013-02-18 12:10:08.326 Giordano.iPhone[5946:c07] Fetching next(): currentItem doens't exist
2013-02-18 12:10:08.762 Giordano.iPhone[5946:c07] displayIfPossible orderId:0
2013-02-18 12:10:08.763 Giordano.iPhone[5946:c07] Fetching next(): currentItem doens't exist
2013-02-18 12:10:09.169 Giordano.iPhone[5946:c07] displayIfPossible orderId:0
2013-02-18 12:10:09.170 Giordano.iPhone[5946:c07] Fetching next(): currentItem doens't exist
2013-02-18 12:10:09.614 Giordano.iPhone[5946:c07] displayIfPossible orderId:0
2013-02-18 12:10:09.615 Giordano.iPhone[5946:c07] Fetching next(): currentItem doens't exist
2013-02-18 12:10:10.116 Giordano.iPhone[5946:c07] displayIfPossible orderId:0
2013-02-18 12:10:10.116 Giordano.iPhone[5946:c07] Fetching next(): currentItem doens't exist
2013-02-18 12:10:10.654 Giordano.iPhone[5946:c07] displayIfPossible orderId:0
```

I opened up the sqlite database and I can see that items have indeed been inserted into the database.

I know multithreading and Core Data can be tricky, and I think I have followed the principles outlined by Apple's concurrency with core data doc.

Any ideas why displayIfPossible is not seeing the right thing?

**EDIT**

code for getItemByOrderId

```
// Returns a newly generated managedObjectContext. Use it for cases without concurrency.

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    return [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
}

- (Item *)getItemByPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setResultType:NSManagedObjectResultType];
    [request setFetchLimit:1];

    NSSortDescriptor *d = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"order_id" ascending:YES
                                                       selector:nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:d]];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    Item *ret = nil;
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *objects = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (objects == nil) {
        // handle the error
    } else {
        if ([objects count] > 0) {
            ret = (Item *)[objects objectAtIndex:0];
        } else if ([objects count] > 1) {
            [NSException raise:@"Duplicated results in core data" format:@"%@", predicate];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

- (Item *)getItemByOrderId:(NSNumber *)orderId {
    NSParameterAssert(orderId);
    return [self getItemByPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"order_id = %@", orderId]];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dropped MR because it's too buggy.

Answer (score 2):

A context does not know about changes in other contexts, unless they were pushed to it from child context. In your case you should listen to `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` from the context that does the save to persistent store and merge changes. Another way would be to spawn a child context in your NSOperation, that will push the changes to it's parent (the one that you use to display items) when fetch is done, but that's totally up to you and depends on app design.